# $regex match pattern has different result in MongoDB vs. Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, mongodb

I am using this `$regex` pattern in a mongo query:

`{domain: {$regex: '^(.+\.)?youtube.com$'}}`

Expecting it to match `youtube.com`, and `sub.youtube.com`.

The problem I'm seeing is that it's matching things like `justyoutube.com`.

In JavaScript, it does not match:

```js
console.log(/^(.+\.)?youtube.com$/.test('justyoutube.com'));
// this returns `false` as expected.
```

Is there some better way to get this working? And is the issue with my regex, or the regex library used by MongoDB?

**Update**: looks like when I use `/pattern/` vs. `'pattern'` i get the results I'm expecting. Still curious how to get it using quotes since I could debug easier in MongoDB Compass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm guessing the `\` in the string you pass is acting as an escape character in the string itself, and doesn't make it into the actual regex. You can try doubling the backslash to sort of 'escape the escape':

```js
const unescaped = new RegExp('^(.+\.)?youtube.com$')
const escaped = new RegExp('^(.+\\.)?youtube.com$')

console.log(unescaped.test('justyoutube.com'));
console.log(escaped.test('justyoutube.com'));

console.log(unescaped.test('sub.youtube.com'));
console.log(escaped.test('sub.youtube.com'));

// Or you can use a template literal, which interprents all its characters literally:

const withBacktick = new RegExp(`^(.+\.)?youtube.com$`);
console.log(withBacktick.test('sub.youtube.com'));
console.log(withBacktick.test('justyoutube.com'));
```

Comment: Thanks! Looks like the extra `\\` fixes it in MongoDB Compass!

Comment: You should also explain this answer in the context of MongoDB.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen I actually don't know the first thing about MongoDB; this was just a guess based on the fact that the regex was passed as a string. But I'd be happy to edit the post if you can clarify what you mean. Would a snippet with OPs original code, but modified to work correctly count?

Comment: I think in MongoDB `\.` is actually behaving like an unescaped regex dot.  This is why the same pattern matches `justyoutube.com`.  Intentional or not, I think your answer is right.